# $(\alpha,\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$, proof

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, permutations

> Let $\alpha,\beta\in S_n$ be permutations. Show $(\alpha,\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$.

I do not know if this holds for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

If I consider $\alpha=(a_1,...,a_k)\:\:\:\:\:\:\beta=(b_1,...,b_I)$

$\alpha(a_i)=a_{i+1}\\\alpha(a_k)=a_{1}\\\alpha(a)=a,\forall{1,...,n}-(a_1,...,a_k)$

$\beta$ is analogous.

If both $\alpha,\beta$ are disjoint. Then we have

$(\alpha\beta(a_i))^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}(a_i)=a_{i-1}=\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}(a_i)$

However I picked up two non-disjoint cycles, in $S_3$:

$(132)$, and $(123)$ to check if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ needed to be disjoint for the property to hold.

If I take the composite permutation on 1 power to minus one, I get $((132)(123)(1))^-1=(1)^{-1}$

**Questions:**

**1)** What does it mean  $(1)^{-1}$? Is $((132)(123)(1))^-1=(1)^{-1}$
 right?

**2)** What do you think of my attempt of proof insofar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $(\alpha,\beta)$ mean?

Comment: Your example you tried to work with is a bad one since $(123)^{-1}=(132)$ and so they commute.  You should try picking two which do *not* commute.  $(1)$ is what some people denote the identity permutation as., the inverse of the identity permutation is again the identity permutation.  As Alex alluded to, the notation $(\alpha,\beta)$ is unusual and unclear what you mean.  If you are asking about $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}$ you should know your "socks and shoes principle" that $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$.  You put on your socks before your shoes.  To reverse, you take off shoes first.

Comment: @AlexProvost                   $ (\alpha\beta) $is the composite permutation.

Comment: @PedroGomes There should be no comma, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove that $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}$, because this would have the consequence that every finite group is abelian. Yes, this would make group theory much easier, but unfortunately it's not true.

The correct relation is $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$, that can be proved by considering that
$$
(\alpha\beta)(\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1})=
\alpha(\beta\beta^{-1})\alpha^{-1}=
\alpha\alpha^{-1}
$$
which is the identity.

As an exercise, prove that $(\alpha\beta)^{-1}=\beta^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$ only holds when $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ (for instance, but not excluding other cases, when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint cycles).

Where does your proof go wrong? Nowhere, actually, in the computations, but you happened to take two commuting permutations. Try with $\alpha=(12)$ and $\beta=(13)$. A proof of a general fact cannot be given by examining a particular case.

Comment: hmmm... unfortunately?

Comment: @suitangi At my alma mater, there used to be a strong group working in finite groups, so we had a joke theorem: ”Every group, except for some unfortunate case, is finite”.

Comment: :) you mean a virtually trivial group?